# How do I export csv file to my computer in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, export

I am trying to export a table from a remote server to my desktop computer in csv format. I have this code:

```
select * from order
into outfile 'C:\Users\Sleep Shop\Desktop\MySQL Scripts/outfile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

but I get this error:

> failed : Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/C:\Users\Sleep Shop\Desktop\MySQL Scripts/outfile.csv' (Errcode: 2)

I'm thinking there is something fundamental I don't understand about this procedure, probably something to do the table being at a remote server. Can anyone help?

I used this code to tell a spot on the server to create the file:

```
select * from orders
into outfile '/var/www/test/outfile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

It creates the file but it contains no records and I get this error:

> failed : Field separator argument is not what is expected;

Comment: Is it this directory exist in your pc ? or you have enough space ?

Comment: How are you accessing the remote server? Using ssh/putty? The remote server is thinking the file path you have given is located somewhere on it's own drive. Notice the error is pointing to a linux location "/var/lib/...". You need to let the server write the CSV file to a valid location on it's own drive, then you can transfer the file to your local PC.

Comment: have you tried changing the path to `C:/Users/Sleep Shop/Desktop/MySQL Scripts/outfile.csv` ?

Comment: This directory exists on my pc, I have plenty of space. I am accessing the server through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I thought it may be a path problem, ok so I will attempt to write to a directory there, is there a resource you can point me to that tells me how to transfer a file?

Comment: You can use phpMyAdmin to download the CSV. Just click on the table, then click the "export" tab and choose "CSV" from the drop down of options there.

Comment: Actually I think I can access that directory on the server via ftp and just grab the file I create that way. Though it would be great to figure out to make transfer to my desktop via SQL

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to use SQL to transfer the file. The only way of automating that sort of thing would be to have some sort of CRON job that keeps checking that directory "/var/lib/mysql/" for a CSV file and then transfers it to your PC.

Answer (score 5):

Change the query like this:

```
select * from `order`
into outfile 'export.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Then you will find the file in your remote server's directory here: /var/lib/mysql/export.csv (or possibly /var/lib/mysql/data/your-db-name/export.csv)

Connect to your server via SSH ([use putty](https://superuser.com/questions/291423/how-to-copy-a-file-without-using-scp-inside-an-ssh-session)) and transfer the file to your PC or move the file to a directory that accepts FTP access and you can download it using an FTP client (ie. filezilla, winSCP).

Or you can use phpMyAdmin and click on the table, then click the "export" tab, and then you will see an option to select "CSV" from the format dropdown. This may not work if your table is too large (depends on phpMyAdmin's settings or PHP's settings on how long a script can run).

Comment: Thanks David, I've done something like that and can create a file in a specified directory, but it's empty, see update above.

Comment: Sorry David, I get this error from it:Failed to execute SQL : SQL select * from order into outfile 'export.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY " ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order into outfile 'export.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY " ESCAPED B' at line 1

Comment: "order" is a reserved word, enclose it inside backticks (see updated query). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: I copy and pasted your code, this is what I got:

Failed to execute SQL : SQL select * from `order` into outfile 'export.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY " ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '" ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'' at line 1

*the tick backs are there they just don't show up in this comment.

Comment: ok, sorry, put the '"' back for enclosed by: ENCLOSED BY '"' The query now works for me, I just tried it.

Comment: we must have some differences in our systems, it just doesn't work for me. thanks for trying, I appreciate it.

Comment: As a final attempt, try: OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\\'

Comment: Hey Dave, this partially works. It retrieves data, makes a csv file located where I want, however all the data is in the same row when opened in excel.

SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/test/outfile.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM orders

Comment: Since you are opening this CSV file on a Windows PC, you'll need to do LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'