# How to separate csv data in columns with expressions?

Tags: csv, jasper-reports, datasource

I have an jrxml report - transposed in csv that takes a field

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{OBSERVATII}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

and that field is from the database and looks like that:

```
CONSUM_ANUAL: 293200 MC PUTERE_CALORICA: .03 GJ/MC FE: .984 mG/GJ
CONSUM_ANUAL: 293200 MC PUTERE_CALORICA: .03 GJ/MC FE: 46 G/GJ
PRODUCTIE: 4389 T/an FE: .1 KG/Mg
```

I want to transpose data in separate columns like CONSUM_ANUAL / PUTERE_CALORICA / FE / PRODUCTIE. I saw that commands like FIND doesn't works - when I execute the report, it brings me an error. The only things that I can use is `.substring(x,y)`, `.length()` but I don't know how to do what I want without a FIND command. Can someone help me with some advice?

Comment: You should prepare the *csv* datasource better. [CSV Data Source Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/csvdatasource/index.html#csvdatasource). For *MySQL* DB you can look at [How do I export csv file to my computer in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16696914/876298) post

Comment: Unfortunatly I have a datasource that I cannot change, I just have to use it...